# Do black holes also exist on a quantum level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, event-horizon, hawking-radiation

I understand that quantum mechanics refutes the concept that black holes can not exist on a quantum level because matter can only be absorbed no emitted from a black hole. However, Hawking's radiation theory states that on a quantum level particles can actually escape from close to if not the event horizon itself. So why then would black holes not exist on quantum level?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the claim that *quantum mechanics refutes the concept that black holes can not exist on a quantum level*. Can you give a link to where you saw this stated?

Comment: _"Quantum mechanics refutes the concept that black holes can not exist on a quantum level"_ is a weirdly worded statement. It means that quantum mechanics says that black holes can exist at a quantum level. But why do you put in the word "refutes" in there then? Outside of quantum mechanics, there is no claim that black holes cannot exist at a quantum level. So, how does quantum mechanics refute anything? It seems that you have wrongly used double negatives in a really confusing way.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, quantum or [micro black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole) can exist, at least as long as we confine our speculation to masses greater than the [Planck mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_mass). However, there is no known mechanism in the current universe (either natural or artificial) for creating micro black holes. It is possible that some [primordial black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primordial_black_hole), created soon after the Big Bang, could have had a small mass, but various attempts to detect primordial black holes have so far not succeeded.

Without a theory of quantum gravity, we have no idea whether black holes smaller than the Planck mass can exist or how they would behave.